# Extending a pre-measure on an sigma-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

> Consider on $\Bbb{R}$ the family $\Sigma $ of all Borel sets which are symmetric w.r.t. the origin, which is a $\sigma $-algebra. Is it possible to extend a pre-measure $\mu $ on $\Sigma $ to a measure on $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ ? If so, is this extension unique.

**Context:** Preparing for my exam

**Effort:**

Firstly, the question doesn't make sense to me. They first claim that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, which I've shown (with some help from MSE). And now they talk about a *pre*-measure. But I thought that a pre-measure is a measure on a set that is **not** a $\sigma$-algebra...

Secondly, I think making an extension, of a *measure* $\mu$ on $\Sigma$ to  $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ is not very difficult. Just given a borel set $B$, make it a symmetric, by for example, taking all positive values of $B$, call it $B_+$ together with $-B_+$. But this doesn't seem unique. Couldn't I also just send all non-symmetric sets to $0$ ?

So my question is, am I thinking stupid, or is this question stupid ?

Comment: You can not send all no symmetric sets to $0$, as this would contradict additivity in general, e.g. because $(0,1) \cup (-1,0)$ is symmetric, but the individual sets in the union are not. But you can possibly (?) give different "weights" to the negative and positive "halves" of the real line.